# Automatically create test page for RESTful webservice

Tags: web-services, rest, client

I have a bunch of RESTful JSON webservices created with Spring WebMVC and I wonder if there's any library or framework that could automatically generate web pages with forms to call these services and test them.

I know some application servers have web control panels that dynamically generate this kind of form when you deploy webservices to them, but I'm trying to find an open source solution that could be embedded in my web app and deployed a simple Tomcat or Jetty server.

Comment: I recently came accross the Swagger project. It's not a completely automatic solution, but it helps a lot. https://developers.helloreverb.com/swagger/